# Understanding difference between Maximum Likelihood and Levenberg Marquardt result

Tags: maximum-likelihood, least-squares, markov-chain-montecarlo, nonlinear-regression, parameterization

In some of my regression results I noticed a deviation between Maximum Likelihood (via Monte Carlo Markov Chain, initialised by parameter result of Nelder-Mead, median value pictured) result and Levenberg Marquardt result. Since the deviation is outside the σ region, I would like to understand the reason why.
The subsequent question would be, how to decide which approach is best suited for approximating the "real" parameter value. For now, I used the Maximum Likelihood approach mainly for detecting correlations and exploring parameter space. The [official website](https://emcee.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/line/) suggests that the Maximum Likelihood method could lead to better parameter values than Levenberg Marquardt. Could you provide a method to evaluate this?

[image]

LM Estimate i_0_an

9.88E-08;   5.80E-08;   3.39E-08;   1.85E-08;   7.96E-09

ML Estimate i_0_an (notice: this is not exactly the same value as pictured in the diagram, since this is the middle value and in the diagram the median value)

7.62E-08;   4.34E-08;   2.52E-08;   1.46E-08;   7.31E-09

Comment: What do you mean by "Maximum Likelihood method could lead to better parameter values than Levenberg Marquardt"? For me you are also doing maximum likelihood estimation with the Marquardt algorithm, it's just another method to compute the maximum likelihood estimator so it can yield different results (but even if they are different they seem pretty close to me). Both methods will give you approximate values of the MLE so it not very surprising that they give slightly different results.

Comment: To my understanding Levenberg Marquardt (LM) leads to the same MLE estimator as Monte Carlo Markov Chain (MCMC) does, when the error was weighted (assumption for dependent variable: Gaussian and independent, weighted on standard deviation of dependent variable) correctly. Since I used MCMC without weights, and it does not tend to run into local minima like LM does, I guessed that the result might be more accurate. Thank you for the answer, generally it does not matter what value I take since both are pretty close.

Comment: I was just confused about why you opposed LM with maximum likelihood because LM is used to do maximum likelihood. I guess on the left panel of your figure you meant maximum likelihood with MCMC? Anyway if you want to assess which one is better you can run simulations where you fix the true value of the parameters then estimate them with both LM and MCMC and compare both methods through bias/variance.

Comment: My mistake, thank you for pointing that out and giving my an idea for validation!